# Registry value data not working as expected through 'REG ADD'

Tags: batch-file, cmd, regedit

I have a program which is supposed to create a listing in the Spacetree through [regedit](/questions/tagged/regedit) additions.

Almost everything is working fine, but my icon isn't showing.

This is the code which is setting the icon:

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{5107667c-149a-47c8-b0c9-e4bf9132f17d}\DefaultIcon /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%Program Files (x86)%\PowerFolder.com\PowerFolder\PowerFolder.exe", /f
```

1. [Full Code]: https://puu.sh/DUhZz/ac147be668.bat
2. [Missing Icon]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV3hh.png
3. [How the Icon should look like]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWsMN.png

What could be the problem?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Can you please post the relevant bits of your code into your question?

Comment: I did, I've posted the code which is supposed to create the Icon, but it didn't work

Comment: I've marked it in a Screenshot for you https://i.imgur.com/SuPRCao.png

Comment: It is clear from your posted code and the external complete content that you have an unexpected additional character on that line, a comma! If it is supposed to be there, can you explain why? otherwise delete it or add the missing number which usually follows it and include both that and the comma within the doublequotes for that data value!

Comment: Yeah thanks! I removed it but it's still not working, maybe theres something else? https://i.imgur.com/N4CgsHZ.png

Comment: I'd expect the command to look a little more like this, `Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{5107667c-149a-47c8-b0c9-e4bf9132f17d}\DefaultIcon" /VE /T REG_EXPAND_SZ /D "%%ProgramFiles(x86)%%\PowerFolder.com\PowerFolder\PowerFolder.exe,0" /F` where the last number, currently `0` would be the icon index from within that resource. If you do not need the number, that's fine, but you really should correct your invalid variable `%Program Files (x86)%` to `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` for a string value, or more correctly, `%%ProgramFiles(x86)%%` for an expandable string as intended.

Comment: Great! It works now, big thanks ^^ life savior https://i.imgur.com/66pXG5L.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) line to look a little more like this:

```bat
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{5107667c-149a-47c8-b0c9-e4bf9132f17d}\DefaultIcon" /VE /T REG_EXPAND_SZ /D "%%ProgramFiles(x86)%%\PowerFolder.com\PowerFolder\PowerFolder.exe,0" /F
```

The `0` in `,0` should be the respective icon index number for that particular resource. If you do not need one, please remove the comma and number suffix:

```bat
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{5107667c-149a-47c8-b0c9-e4bf9132f17d}\DefaultIcon" /VE /T REG_EXPAND_SZ /D "%%ProgramFiles(x86)%%\PowerFolder.com\PowerFolder\PowerFolder.exe" /F
```

You'll note that you're setting the data type as `REG_EXPAND_SZ` which means that the data should contain a variable to be expanded when required. If you do not require that feature, you should use a data type of `REG_SZ`, *(which is the default and does not need to be stipulated in your command)*, and reduce the doubled percents to expand the variable during the addition of the data:

```bat
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{5107667c-149a-47c8-b0c9-e4bf9132f17d}\DefaultIcon" /VE /D "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PowerFolder.com\PowerFolder\PowerFolder.exe" /F
```